# Reducing Android App Size

Tags: android, apk

I just released a simple app on Google Play, and I realized the file size ended up as 37M! My app consists of 100+ PNGs how could I reduce the file size to below 10?

Comment: I don't understand why you posted this question here. Use smaller or fewer PNGs.

Comment: Google how to reduce picture file sizes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [tinypng](https://tinypng.com/). I use it A LOT for my android projects and it GREATLY reduces the size of all your png files! :)

Comment: Considering that the app is only 37MB, that would mean the resulting app would be -13MB in size, which seems unlikely. :-) BTW, apparently **`pngquant`** does the same sort of thing as the tinypng site, if you would prefer to do it all locally: http://pngquant.org/

Comment: @CommonsWare Just to clarify, seeing that this answer has negative score. Reducing the size of png files is a good idea anyway, isn't it?

Comment: But what's with the downvotes, I made a chess app that kept having out of memory exceptions up until I compressed all of my png files...

Comment: @Szymon: I have no idea why this was downvoted. I am not aware of any particular problems with using tinypng/pngquant to optimize an image, though you'd want to do your own testing. All else being equal, smaller PNG file sizes are better, at least for distribution. Note that none of this will impact the heap utilization of the images, just how much disk space they will take up.

Comment: @Clay Remove your claim about saving 50MB as this is clearly untrue.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to export your png's to jpg's. If no transparency needed, of course.

Comment: Why would this get downvoted? I was just about to say the exact same thing. +1